# Flink checkpoint relate to kafka partitions?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

so i tried look for it in the Flink documentation but couldn`t find any answer.

I have a Flink app "Kafka Source->Operations->Window->Kafka Sink".
Checkpoint Configuration is:

1. 10 seconds interval
2. around 30MB of state size
3. each checkpoint take less than 1second+-
4. EXCACLY_ONCE on kafka producer configuration.

When i try to submit the job with checkpoint enabled on topic with 30+ partitions, the checkpoint success , but when i run the same code (with the same resources and parallelisem) on topic (the sink topic) with 2 partitions for example, it keeping failing (after reach the timeout).

So i try to look for it, but couldn`t find a good explanation, is the number of kafka sink partitions is related to checkpoint? if it does, then how?

Comment: Please tell what was the number of partitions for source Kafka topic and Flink source parallelism.

Comment: If you have done multiple experiments, please add the details for them separately.

Comment: @Chuckskull The number of partition is equal to the number of the parallelism (27, or 35 i can`t remmber right now), and i didn`t make multiple experiments, only the expermient above (Running with different kafka topic`s partitions). any clue / explanation?